# How do I sample raster values using points?

Tags: r, raster

bio_var is a stack of 6 cropped raster files  from worldclim (10m resolution). I am getting the following error. I was trying to extract raster values using an occurrence dataset

`raster:extract (bio_var[[2]], Burk_spatialP)`

but i got the below error.

> raster:extract(bio_var[[2]], Burk_spatialP) : NA/NaN argument

I have used the following code to crop the raster

`BIO<-crop(bio,lanka, mask=TRUE)`
bio is the rasterstack of climatic variables from worldclim.

I am not sure what is the reason behind it. May I know how can I resolve it?

Thanks Rahul[image: cropped raster of Sri Lanka and the points]

Comment: might be the error in invoking the `extract()` function from `raster` package? Try using double colon x2 like `raster::extract()`

Comment: Thanks@ Grzegorz Sapijaszko. It WORKED.